# Input tag: nothing typed is appearing

Tags: reactjs, forms, input

My first React session data storage, so thanks. I am trying to set up inputing data and then placing it in session storage, so it can be edited, viewed or deleted later. There are 2 pieces of data, "title" and "note" to be inputed into a form. Nothing happens when I type into the form inputs. Any other help welcome also.

```
class AddNote extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getFormData();
    }

    //let notes = getSessionItem(keys.notes);
    //if (!notes) { notes = ""; }

    onTitleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ title: event.target.value }, this.storeFormData);
        this.storeFormData();
    }

    onContentChange(event) {
        this.setState({ content: event.target.value }, this.storeFormData);
    }

    storeFormData() {
        const form = {
            title: this.state.title,
            content: this.state.content
        }
        setSessionItem(keys.user_form, form);
    }

    getFormData() {
        const form = getSessionItem(keys.user_form);
        if (form) {
            this.setState({
                title: form.name,
                content: form.content
            });
        }
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h2>ADD NOTE PAGE</h2>
                </div>

                <form classname="nav1">
                    <div>
                        <label><b>Title</b></label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={this.state.title}
                            onchange={this.onTitleChange.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label><b>Content</b></label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={this.state.content}
                            onchange={this.onContentChange.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNote;
```

and the storage file:

```
export const keys = {
    title: 'title',
    notes: 'notes'
}

export const getSessionItem = function (key) {
    let item = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    item = JSON.parse(item);
    return item;
}

export const setSessionItem = function (key, value) {
    value = JSON.stringify(value);
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

export const removeSessionItem = function (key) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Comment: Hi John, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to have 2 change handler for your input. You can do it using a common change handler.

```
<form classname="nav1">
    <div>
        <label><b>Title</b></label>
        <input type="text"
            value={this.state.title}
            name="title"       <---- Provide name here
            onChange={this.onChange}
        />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label><b>Content</b></label>
        <input type="text"
            value={this.state.content}
            name="content"       <---- Provide name here
            onChange={this.onChange}
        />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Your `onChange` function should be, and use callback in setState to call your `storeFormData` function.

```
onChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
   }, () => this.storeFormData())
}
```

**Note:** In `React` we use `camelCase`, for example, `onchange` should be `onChange` and `classname` should be `className`.

Also make sure you bind `this` to `storeFormData` and `getFormData` functions, or you can use arrow function's to automatically bind `this`.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e4yaip)